# images are not displayed on aspx web page

Tags: webforms

i am programming a webform application, that displays images. currently using localserver
the code looks like this:

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Data/")))
        {
            ImageButton ib = new ImageButton();
            ib.ImageUrl = file;
            ib.Width = Unit.Pixel(100);
            ib.Height = Unit.Pixel(100);
            ib.Style.Add("padding", "2px");
            ib.Click += imageButton_Click;
            Panel1.Controls.Add(ib);
        }
    }

    private void imageButton_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

the webcode looks like this:

```
    src="file:///C:/folder/WebApplication1/Data/Chrysanthemum.jpg"
```

Which looks fine.
On the webpage the panel is displayes, but the images are not, only placeholders.

Please help i am really nubi in asp.net

Comment: The problem is not as such related to .NET but to the path of your file. The physical path on the server is certainly not what you want to use, you should store your images in any folder inside your webroot and point to it in your HTML source.

Comment: How is it different from what I did? i used Server.MapPath(), the folder is inside the webroot

Comment: cfr my answer... don't worry this is a common mistake. It's important to understand the difference between the physical path and the webpath though. You could keep the exact same physical path but by changing your IIS configuration the webpath might be totally different. basically your website users shouldn't know nor have any clue about your folder hierarchy server-side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MapPath` gives you the physical path of a file or folder inside your server.
In order to display your images on a webpage, you need either to use a webpath, either absolute or relative to your site or the page being displayed. Basically, you would just need to change this in your code :

```
ib.ImageUrl = file;
```

should be

```
ib.ImageUrl = "/data/" + Path.GetFileName(file);
```